# Looking for a cause of random EAccessViolation in SysUtils.Format / System.Move

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I'm (users of my application are) experiencing weird EAccessViolation errors with a piece of code having no bad programming logic. The DisplayData function simply sets the caption of a label - no compile time errors, no bad data send to the SysUtils.Format() function.

MadExcept call stack looks like:

```
main thread ($1860):
00406a33 +067 MyApp.exe System            137   +0 Move
00452c9e +13e MyApp.exe System.SysUtils            AddBuf
0045365d +931 MyApp.exe System.SysUtils            WideFormatBuf
004528c0 +014 MyApp.exe System.SysUtils            FormatBuf
00452ab4 +0c0 MyApp.exe System.SysUtils            FmtStr
004529d2 +00e MyApp.exe System.SysUtils            Format
004529b7 +01b MyApp.exe System.SysUtils            Format
00b3aa55 +185 MyApp.exe mainunit     1506  +14 TMainForm.DisplayData
```

The error does not appear always, the function can be called few times (same parameters) and no error, then an error at random times.

I'm guessing there's some issue with memory here (there is enough available memory) - but have no idea how to help the user - or where to look for the cause.

Any ideas to what could be happening here ?

... as asked by David to show the real code, here goes:

```
TRadioButton(rgOperation.Controls[Integer(SelectedItem.Operation)]).Caption :=
TRadioButton(rgOperation.Controls[Integer(SelectedItem.Operation)]).Caption +
Format(' %s',[SelectedItem.History.OperationOn.TargetStr]);
```

Where:
rgOperation is a TRadioGroup. There are 4 radio buttons in the group.
SelectedItem.Operation is an enum (0..3). SelectedItem.History.OperationOn.TargetStr is a string. Nothing in a call to SelectedItem.History.OperationOn is nil.

Comment: You are sending `Format` bad data. You clearly think that is not the case, but the evidence says otherwise. You need to isolate the problem. Concentrate on making a concise repro.

Comment: @David: It is really a simple Format statement, something like     Label1.Caption := Format('%s', [Edit.Text]); As said, calling the same a few time in a row - no error, calling a few times more - error at random calls.

Comment: It really is a problem in your code. We've all been there. "I can't understand how this can fail, it must be a bug in the compiler/library/operating system." It's a seductive thought. Don't be seduced. All the evidence points to a fault in your code. What's more, please don't expect us to get too excited when you won't post real code. Again, we've seen this so many times. When somebody says, the code is something like blah blah blah, on so many times it turns out not to be the case. Don't be shy. Show the actual code. You never know, it could be bogus.

Comment: What if we consider for a moment it really is not a problem in my code. Running the same application, same parameters on another machine in that company - no issues at all. No issues at all with the same for all other users.

Comment: Yeah, some faults are like that. Common example is passing address of memory that has been freed. Often times the memory manager has not returned the memory to system, and it's not been overwritten with anything else. And so your code works. But then other times that's not the case and the code fails.I honestly don't understand why you ask for help but then reject the help and decline the invitation to provide actual code. If you don't want to provide any code then you should probably work on the problem yourself.

Comment: `SelectedItem.History.OperationOn.TargetStr` is pretty different from `Edit1.Text`. May not look so, but it is. Loads of scope for a screw up there.

Comment: Split the "Format(' %s',[SelectedItem.History.OperationOn.TargetStr]);" into several lines, where you first do Hist:=SelectedItem.History; then OpOn:=Hist.OperationOn; and finally TgStr:=OpOn.TargetStr; Then use the TgStr in your Format statement. It'll most likely at some point never reach the Format statement, but will halt with an exception on one of the assignments, and then you have found your culprit. If the exception still ends up in your Format call, then it could be a memory overwrite on the string variable or (unlikely) the code of the Format routine itself.

Comment: Another hint is which address the access violation occurs at. Is it a "Read of address 0000????" access violation (ie. a very low address) then it is most likely a NIL reference. If it is a high address, then it is most likely an orphaned pointer (pointer to memory that is no longer has valid content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
Format('%s', [SelectedItem.History.OperationOn.TargetStr])
```

leads to an access violation inside `Format` then the only reasonable conclusion to draw is that

```
SelectedItem.History.OperationOn.TargetStr
```

is invalid. So, perhaps `SelectedItem.History.OperationOn` are all valid, but `TargetStr` is invalid. That's perhaps not so likely because I presume that `TargetStr` is a string and you have to work pretty hard to corrupt string variables.

More likely is that `SelectedItem` or `History` or `OperationOn` is invalid. Perhaps one of these refer to an object that has been destroyed and re-used by the memory manager. Your use of the stale reference could then lead to the error you observe.

You may well find that the full FastMM memory manager running in full debug mode helps identify the fault. If you are using an object after it has been destroyed, then full debug FastMM very likely will identify that for you.

Comment: Yes, my idea also .. it is just that I'm looking and looking and am unable to find  where and when and how any of those could be set to "invalid". What's puzzling me is that the same works with other machines (completely the same "setup" of parameters)

Comment: That's not puzzling at all. That's normal. Memory managers don't always make memory invalid immediately. Non-repeatability is a classic symptom of this type of error. Use FastMM in full debug mode.